# Как убрать дату поста в теме WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Привет! Уже 3 час пытаюсь найти функцию ответственную за вывод даты поста. Увы, безрезультатно. Тема [Emphaino](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/emphaino/)
Перерыл все файлы, так и не нашел.
**Подскажите где искать? Может есть плагин который может помочь в этом?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл:
**emphaino\inc\template-tags.php**

Comment: В точку! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

В файле content.php вызывается  на 48 строке.

1. Искать в sublime text 3: file > open folder.
2. Выбираем нужную папку второй кнопкой "find in folder" и
3. находим в файле inc/template-tags.php на 130 стр. функцию emphaino_posted_on();